# What is a postgresql scalar JSON?

Tags: postgresql

I have a JSON column that contains some data inserted from an external app.

Here is an example of such a json:

```
{"static":[{"key":"erferf","value":"refreref"},{"key":"aaa","value":"aaa"}],"user_data":[{"key":"aaaa","value":"##CUSTOM001##"}],"dynamic":[{"key":"aaa","title":"aaaa","type":"string","required":true}]}
```

When I try to select the first key by the following syntax

```
select some_json_column->>'static'
```

I get NULL.

I think it has something to do with it being a SCALAR Json.

Can anyone give me a lead on what i am doing wrong?

Shaby

Comment: Some code blocks may make this easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your json data isn't scalar, it's composite. Take a look:

```
-- Simple scalar/primitive value
-- Primitive values can be numbers, quoted strings, true, false, or null
SELECT '5'::json;

-- Array of zero or more elements (elements need not be of same type)
SELECT '[1, 2, "foo", null]'::json;

-- Object containing pairs of keys and values
-- Note that object keys must always be quoted strings
SELECT '{"bar": "baz", "balance": 7.77, "active": false}'::json;

-- Arrays and objects can be nested arbitrarily
SELECT '{"foo": [true, "bar"], "tags": {"a": 1, "b": null}}'::json;
```

BTW, I cannot reproduce your error:

```
--It'll return json object as expected
WITH sample (json_column) AS (
    VALUES ('{"static":[{"key":"erferf","value":"refreref"},{"key":"aaa","value":"aaa"}],"user_data":[{"key":"aaaa","value":"##CUSTOM001##"}],"dynamic":[{"key":"aaa","title":"aaaa","type":"string","required":true}]}'::JSON)
)
SELECT json_column->>'static' FROM sample;
```

More info about json [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. when I ran you code to repreduce it - i get the static key value, but for some reason when I select it from the database it returns NULL. any idea why?

Comment: Probably 'static' key isn't in top-level of your JSON, please provide exactly `SQL` that you're using and a table sample (not just JSON sample).

Answer (score 0):

It might be super late, but my answer may help someone else.

I had the similar issue. It turns out that my JSON was stored as a string and it had quotes and etc. Hence, when I convert into jsonb using `columnName:jsonb`, it was creating a malformed JSON. As a result, when I query directly from the db, I was getting null data.

I was able to fix this by `columnName#>>'{}')::jsonb`. I found this fix from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824247/convert-json-string-to-jsonb).