# Convert JSON string to JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with `jsonb` field. Some of the rows are an array of objects, but some of the others are string.

[image]

I want to convert red rows to array of objects.

My table structure:

[image]

How I can do this in `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following SQL should do the trick:

```
update your_table_name 
set content =  (content#>>'{}')::jsonb 
where jsonb_typeof(content)='string';
```

Reference:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html