# PostgresSQL - Converting String in JSONB to Actual JSONB, Error: Token is invalid

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble working with the JSONB structure in PostgreSQL. currently my data is saved as follows:

```
"{\"Hello\":\"World\",\"idx\":0}"
```

Which obviously is not correct  so I am trying to "repair" this and get the actual JSON representation for querying with:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(trim('"' FROM json_data::text), '\\"', '"', 'g')::jsonb FROM My_table
```

However when trying this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "Рыба" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...х, как : Люди X, Пароль \\"Рыба...
SQL state: 22P02
```

So I am thinking that this is due to the character encoding that is not being accepted by the JSONB standard.

My main question then is though, how can I repair this kind of table so that I am still able to query it?  I tried utilizing `conver_from` and `convert_to` but am unable to figure out how to fix this error... did anyone encounter this already?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09b2466eb15ef71713d65f3040278ff3) Please [edit] the question and provide a [example] with which this can be reproduced. Provide the `CREATE` statement of the table and sample data as `INSERT` statements. It might  not harm if you tagged your Postgres version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Found it! (thanks to [Convert JSON string to JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824247/convert-json-string-to-jsonb)), utilizing

```sql
SELECT (json_data#>>'{}')::jsonb FROM my_table
```

fixed it